# Tabs on the side of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid

I'm starting WPF. I need a tab on the sides of the screen; I do not know how to open that tab.

I do know how to open solution explorer but not other things like properties, notifications and toolbox.

Comment: Use the View menu to reactivate panes you might have closed.

Comment: Take your time and explore menus carefully. `Window/Reset Window layout` could be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Please see the below screenshot, just click the ones you want then pin them as needed

[image]